# what c++ for feedforward neural network do you suggest?

Tags: c++, neural-network

I want to do some classification problem (word sense disambiguation) in c++; and I need a a feedforward neural network (MLP). I know there are many libraries but I want the one that is not very large, I need just MLP and , and easy to learn and get work?
I'v read about OpenCV and FANN, but I have no idea which library is best?

Comment: :)) how can I accept them? I dont know!

Comment: thank You! I accept two answers that really helped me! I am new to this site and soon I would learn everything about it

Comment: C/C++ Perceptron: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ccperceptron/

Comment: C/C++ Neural Networks: http://sourceforge.net/projects/c-c-neural-networks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FANN looks fantastic, and has very helpful introduction/getting started sections on its website ([here](http://leenissen.dk/fann/wp/help/getting-started/) and a PDF [here](http://fann.sf.net/fann_en.pdf) for example). The MLP is a fairly straightforward concept for neural networks so your work should be well within the capabilities of the library.

With regard to size, you only need to include the bits of the library you intend to use.

Some more info on the basics of Neural networks [here](http://www.nd.com/neurosolutions/products/ns/whatisNN.html) if you need it. Although if you're tackling word sense disambiguation you probably know more about them already.

I'm not sure why you'd want to use OpenCV, since that's really intended for graphics processing. Are you trying to grab additional input for your MLP from video recording of a speaker?

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. No, I had just heard about openCV and I wanted to know if it is useful me!